# How to view Routes pod in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I have created a routes for my service in the OpenShift,

```
oc get routes

NAME              HOST/PORT                             PATH      SERVICES          PORT 
simplewebserver   simpleweb.apps.devcluster.os.fly.com            simplewebserver   9999
```

When I ran command: curl http://simpleweb.apps.devcluster.os.fly.com/world

it failed to access my web service. I suspect my route has some problem, but I could not see any route debug information.

My question is, how to find the route pod in the OpenShift Or how to find some route activity information when I access route?

Comment: Can you include the specific error message you see when trying to access your web service?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As there is limited information about your problem. Here are few things you can try.

1. Try to curl using a port
   `curl -kv http://simpleweb.apps.devcluster.os.fly.com:9999`
2. Access the pod logs for which the route was created. Check the service `simplewebserver` is using the correct selector to route the traffic to the pod.
   Do a `oc describe service simplewebserver` to see the selectors being used.
3. Check if any network policy is blocking the external traffic.
4. Check if you can access the target pod using that service from within the same namespace. You can do that by rsh to a pod and then access the service using:
   `curl -kv http://servicename.projectname.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Is it possible to check OpenShift router pods?

Comment: What's the output of the the curl you are trying ?

Comment: ```
curl -kv http://simpleweb.apps.devcluster.os.fly.com/world

*   Trying 9.30.180.222...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to simpleweb.apps.devcluster.os.fly.com (9.30.180.222) port 80 (#0)
> GET /world HTTP/1.1
> Host: simpleweb.apps.devcluster.os.fly.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
```

Comment: Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Comment: 503 is pretty generic. I can only think of the following which I already mentioned-->1. Check if your service is using the right selector
2. `oc get endpoints simplewebserver` to check if the services points to the correct endpoints.
3. Confirm if the pod is ready and the traffic
4. Confirm that the route is pointing to the correct service/port

Comment: Also, I see that you have a service on port `9999` and you are trying to curl on port 80?

Comment: Yes, I will curl on port 80, port 9999 is my service port.

Comment: The issue has fixed. I recreate a clean namespace, it works now. The previous namespace is associated Istio member roll, I suspect Istio has impact on my route.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the router logs in logs container of router pods. in our OCP cluster i could see router pods in openshift-ingress namespace.

```
oc get pods -n openshift-ingress
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
router-default-5f9c4b6cb4-12121a   2/2     Running   0          40h
router-default-5f9c4b6cb4-12133a   2/2     Running   0          40h
```

To get the logs, use below command,

```
oc -n openshift-ingress -c logs logs -f <router_pod_name>
```

Also make sure haproxy logs are enabled to find out urls getting hit via router.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3397701

Comment: Hi, in your environment, pod has two containers. But somehow in my environment, I only see pod with only one container. My question is, what container do I miss? Or how to deploy another container as you have

Comment: It depends on number of replicas configured in the deployment, 2 containers in my area serves the same purpose to route the traffic to target services